# Avoiding overflow when comparing between 16-bit numbers

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have a 16-bit number system. and let $a, b$ a 16-bit numbers in this system. 
I know that the numbers I can represent in this system are between $−32,768$ and $32,767$.

Let's say I want to compare between $a$ and $b$ where $a, b$ are near those limits. for example: $a=30,000$ and $b=-30,000$.
I want to compare these numbers using only logical operators (using assembly-like language). I mean that I can't use '$<$' or '$>$' and I can use '$==$' only to compare with $0$.

So I thought about this idea:
for determining if $a==b$, I can use the XOR and then check if the result equals $0$.

I want to figure out how to determine, using this method, if a is greater than b or if a is less than b?

I want hints and good thoughts, and maybe a different ideas than mine. In addition, if you think that the XOR'ing idea isn't useful or it won't work, I'd like to know why.

Comment: This cross into the realm of EEE, since you insist using only propositional logic operators. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157565/which-4-bit-binary-number-is-greater

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using `<`?